# Включение файлов из разных папок C++ VS code

Tags: c++, файловая-система

При разделении кода на файлы и папки столкнулся с проблемой включения .cpp и .h файлов.

---

Есть дерево файлов:

1 String (папка проекта)

1.1 .vscode (папка vs code)

1.1.1 settings.json

1.1.2 tasks.json

1.2 headers (папка с заголовочными файлами)

1.2.1 String.h

1.3 sourse (папка с файлами ресурсов)

1.4 main.cpp (файл захода в программу)

[image: древо файлов]

в String.h находится объявление класса String, а в String.cpp его реализация. В main.cpp вызывается класс String и пара его методов через вызов заголовочного файла.

---

main.cpp

```
#include"headers/String.h"

int main()
{
    String str("lorem");
    str.Print();
    
    return 0;
}
```

String.h

```
#pragma once

class String
{
private:
    char* str;
public:
    String();
    ~String();
    void Print();
    //...
}
```

String.cpp

```
#include<String\headers\String.h>
#include<iostream>

String::String(){
    //...
}
String::~String(){
    //...
}
void String::Print(){
    //...
}
```

и пришлось добавить в tasks.json аргумент String.cpp чтобы компилятор его увидел.

tasks.json

```json
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe сборка активного файла",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}","${fileDirname}\\source\\String.cpp",//здесь 
                "-I",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Задача создана отладчиком."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

и в итоге возникает ошибка в String.cpp

```
fatal error: String\headers\String.h: No such file or directory
2 | #include"String\headers\String.h"
  |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Я честно говоря не понимаю почему так происходит и возможно ошибка намного проще чем мне кажется.

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: "String\headers\String.h" : BackSlash '\' в строке это спецсимвол, за которым следует управляющая буква. попробуйте "String\\headers\\String.h" или "String/headers/String.h"

Comment: @AlexGlebe правила строковых литералов не распространяется на директиву `#include` Но слэши действительно универсальнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В проекте нет пути "String\headers\String.h". Или "String/headers/String.h"

При использовании g++ `#include "String\\headers\\String.h"`  приводит к следующему

1. Ведется поиск такого в папке с `.cpp` файлом (только для `include` c кавычками).
2. Ведется поиск в папках, указанных с помощью ключа компиляции `-I`.
3. Ведется поиск в папках, указанных с помощью ключа компиляции `-iquote` (только для `include` c кавычками).
4. Ведется поиск в папках, указанных с помощью ключа компиляции `-isystem` или в системных.

*Реальное же положение файла здесь `headers/String.h` при компиляции main.cpp или `../headers/String.h`  для String.cpp.*

Директива `#include <String\headers\String.h>` заставляет искать подпуть `String\headers\String.h` в системных папках и тех, что указаны с помощью `-I`.

Чтобы сработал "String\headers\String.h", с помощью -iquote надо задать путь к папке, в которой содержится папка проекта. Это неудобно - Visual Studio "не любит" путей с двумя точками, выходящих за пределы папки проекта.

Проще использовать "headers\String.h" и ключ -I, указывающий на корень проекта, но у этого есть недостатки - зависимость от среды разработки. Например с CMake вообще можно использовать только имена файлов, а  в список добавить перечень всех папок.

Переносимым способом, не зависящим от инструментов, является использования реального относительного пути (см.выше).

Comment: А не могли бы подсказать, как конкретно должен выглядеть аргумент. Просто, честно говоря в командах компилятора только начал разбираться и по этому не очень хорошо понимаю о чем речь.

Comment: Обратные слеши в include - всегда ошибка, потому что не кросс-платформенно. Правильно - `/`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat готов согласиться на 100%. Но некоторые инструменты принятые в компаниях (в том числе и отечественные) раньше в принципе не работали со слэшами на Винде - хотя cl.exe и студия  поддерживали. В таком случае приходится заносить пути в проектные настройки. У меня -то написаны прямые.  ) По-хорошему еще заглавные буквы не стоит использовать